# Chrome Extension: Cannot get background to sendMessage to content-script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.0.9",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "my App",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "js/vendors/jquery-3.3.1.min.js",
                "js/content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "js/background.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

and here are my scripts:

```
// background.js
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    setInterval(() => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, 'some-message');
    }, 3000);
});

// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('in runtime')
    console.log(msg);
});

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('in extensions')
    console.log(msg);
});
```

I never get anything logged; what am I missing here?

Comment: What is the actual goal here? Currently the code doesn't make a lot of sense: 1) your background script runs just once and sends messages every 3 seconds to the tab that was active at that time, but it may get closed later, 2) your content script runs on all https pages, but not on http, which doesn't make a lot of sense usually, 3) your content script uses the ancient deprecated chrome.extension.onMessage which is just an alias for chrome.runtime.onMessage so you're registering two different listeners for the same event.

Comment: @wOxxOm I could not get the messaging to work; thought it might be a timing/initialization issue so I decided to just send one every 3 second to see if I can receive any message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your manifest

```
"permissions": ["tabs"]
```

Another problem is the with the tabs[0].id. The id obtained after executing this statement is not matching with the actual id of your tab in the browser. To make this work, execute this function when some event occurs. I am making your background.js to send message when the onUpdated event takes place.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(id, changeInfo, tab){
    setInterval(()=>{       
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(id, "hellooo from background");
    },3000);
});
```

Update your chrome extension, go to a new page and this should start working.